# Phono preamp, one channel doesn't work

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, preamp

I have built a stereo preamp using this circuit (taken from here [Hi-Fi Phono Preamp Rod Elliott - ESP](https://sound-au.com/project06.htm)), but for some reason I can't get the right channel to work at all while the left one plays.

[image]

Now I realize the circuit here is shown for one channel only, but my op amps are duals so I've connected everything the same way for the right channel. Yet it's too weak, it's almost mute. Almost all of the components I've put are exactly the same as in the circuit. The only difference is 2.7k resistor, in my PCB one channel has a 1/2 watt resistor and another is 1/4 watt. Also 22uf caps, in one channel they are 50v, in another 100v. But why would that affect anything? I've even tried different op-amps and film capacitors, but it makes no difference at all. I've checked all the connections several times. I've checked every component for resistance and capacitance as well. Obviously I've connected grounding to the vinyl player. I've tried different PSUs even, one with +8v and -8v, another with +12v and -12v. None of this helps. Another strange thing is, the moment I disconnect one of the channels from the preamp, a horrible interference appears in the other channel. What have I done wrong?

Comment: switch L and R inputs to the pre-amp

Comment: Follow the signal with a scope

Answer (score 1):

> Another strange thing is, the moment I disconnect one of the channels from the preamp, a horrible interference appears in the other channel. What have I done wrong?

You need some decoupling capacitors on the power supply pins of each opamp. It would seem that you're getting oscillation via feedback through the power supply.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the ground is broken in one input lead - not the one that you remove, the other. If everything else is floating the circuit might hum when you pull it.

If you have a tone generator apply a low level sine to each side in turn, compare the two sides with a scope. Pay attention to DC biasses.

Answer (score 0):

The 22uF capacitors are for the ground connection, and if they aren't biased with a significant voltage, they can decay (and will go bad on the shelf, too).  If one of those capacitors has gone open-circuit, there
will be  no significant gain.   Without the capacitor, both
gain stages are voltage followers (zero dB voltage gain).

Find some fresh, lower-voltage units (nonpolar if possible) and replace 'em, and/or swap in some 
capacitors that have been given a DC bias (like, with a 9V battery)
overnight.   Jumpering from 'in' to (-15V) and leaving
the unit powered for a few hours will have a similar effect.

Comment: I was really confused by polarized caps with the positive side connected downwards - wut. In light of C2 only  being  in a feedback circuit that's only loaded with the input of the second opamp, well, I'd scale up all the components to be able to avoid havin 22 µF (instead, 2.2 µF, maybe?) and go for cheaper, better ceramic caps. On the other hand, I've never had an electrolytic capacitor go bad on shelf for the nearly 20 years I've been having shelves with electronic components, so I'd appreciate a source for that claim.

Comment: likewise. I've been dealing in (pro)audio since the mid 80's on and off, and regularly service stuff built in that era. I have seen electrolytic caps start to go low value (not o/c) but only when the are in gear that runs pretty hot. I have never seen or heard of this story about them having problems when not biased, neither is it mentioned by gurus such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Self . So honestly, I call bs on this one.

Comment: The polarity of the 22uF capacitors is odd (usually, one would want the outer case, (-) to be grounded), but there are two failure modes that might be relevant.   One is insulation perforation (leakage) which is addressed by manufacturers by a 'reformation' or 'reconditioning; see here <https://www.illinoiscapacitor.com/pdf/Papers/reconditioning_aluminum_electrolytic.pdf>     There is also seal rupture/drying-out, but leakage current can saturate the op amps, so that's my first thought.